# General solution to finite interval simple wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have a wave equation  with fixed interval with the following initial and boundary conditions.

$$u_{tt} = u_{xx}$$
$$u(x, 0) = \phi(x) = x(1-x)$$
$$u_t(x, 0) = x^3 - x$$
$$u(0, t) = u(1, t) = 0$$

With $c = 1$ and $l = 1$, we can apply the  general solutions stated by Walter A. Strauss in his Book  "Partial Differential Equations: And Introduction"( 2nd edition, 2009. Chapter 3.2, "The Finite Interval" section, p.63 - p.65 ):

$$u(x, t) = \frac{1}{2} \phi(x - ct + 2l) - \frac{1}{2} \phi(4 - x -ct)  +\int_{x - ct + 2l} ^{4 - x -ct} \psi(s) \frac{ds}{2}$$.

By substituting $c = 1$ and $l = 1$, I get that

$$\frac{1}{2} \phi(x - ct + 2l) - \frac{1}{2} \phi(4 - x -ct) = 2tx - 2t - 5x + 5$$

and that:

$$\int_{x - ct + 2l} ^{4 - x -ct} \psi(s) \frac{ds}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( -\frac{(4 - t - x)^2}{2} + \frac{(4 - t - x)^4}{4} + \frac{(2 - t + x)^2}{2} - \frac{(2 - t + x)^4}{4} \right)$$

If I sum up both parts I get $u(x, t)$, but, $u(0, t) \ne u(1, t)$, which contradicts the initial and boundary conditions. What am I doing wrong? Is it incorrect to apply this solution to this case?

Comment: @Gonçalo, thank you. Yes, I can't apply this method to this equation, what's the correcto way of solving this PDE?

Comment: @Gonçalo, I was looking for alternative ways of solving this equation, I don't like to use separation of variables because I always get lost with the integrals, sins and cosines. But it seems that there is no way out. I forgot to tell that $u : [0, 1] \times \mathbb{R}$